# groupby() using two arrays in julia?

Tags: arrays, group-by, julia

I have two arrays with same dimension:

```
a1 = [1,1,3,4,6,6]
a2 = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
```

And I want to group both of them with respect to array `a1` and get the mean of the array `a2` for each group.
My output is coming from array `a2`, as mentioned below:

```
result:
1.5
3.0
4.0
5.5
```

Please suggest an approach to achieve this task.
Thanks!!

Comment: Discourse: https://discourse.julialang.org/t/groupby-on-two-individual-arrays/59643

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a solution using DataFrames.jl:

```
julia> using DataFrames, Statistics

julia> df = DataFrame(a1 = [1,1,3,4,6,6], a2 = [1,2,3,4,5,6]);

julia> combine(groupby(df, :a1), :a2 => mean)
4×2 DataFrame
 Row │ a1     a2_mean
     │ Int64  Float64
─────┼────────────────
   1 │     1      1.5
   2 │     3      3.0
   3 │     4      4.0
   4 │     6      5.5
```

EDIT:

Here are the timings (as usual in Julia you need to remember that the first time you run some function it has to be compiled which takes time):

```
julia> using DataFrames, Statistics

(@v1.6) pkg> st DataFrames # I am using main branch, as it should be released this week
      Status `D:\.julia\environments\v1.6\Project.toml`
  [a93c6f00] DataFrames v0.22.7 `https://github.com/JuliaData/DataFrames.jl.git#main`

julia> df = DataFrame(a1=rand(1:1000, 10^8), a2=rand(10^8)); # 10^8 rows in 1000 random groups

julia> @time combine(groupby(df, :a1), :a2 => mean); # first run includes compilation time
  3.781717 seconds (6.76 M allocations: 1.151 GiB, 6.73% gc time, 84.20% compilation time)

julia> @time combine(groupby(df, :a1), :a2 => mean); # second run is just execution time
  0.442082 seconds (294 allocations: 762.990 MiB)
```

Note that e.g. data.table (if this is your reference) on similar data is noticeably slower:

```
> library(data.table) # using 4 threads
> df = data.table(a1 = sample(1:1000, 10^8, replace=T), a2 = runif(10^8));
> system.time(df[, .(mean(a2)), by = a1])
   user  system elapsed 
   4.72    1.20    2.00
```

Comment: thanks for this amazing suggestion, highly appreciate it !!!

Comment: i am scared of time and memory taken during conversion, as the final test data can be huge, is there any way to achieve this with using only arrays?

Comment: I can do this `Array(combine(DataFrames.groupby((DataFrame(:a=>a, :a2=>a2)), :a1), :a2=>mean))[:, 2]` but may i ask is it going to be time consuming on bigger data in comparison?

Comment: The memory taken is only in the first run, as the code needs to be compiled. The operation should be fast even for large arrays. I will update the post with a larger example. If you want to use pure arrays, you can check out SplitApplyCombine.jl package, but it is likely to be slower on this test case.

Comment: thanks for the detailed explanation, in this scenario, I will stick to this :)

Answer (score 4):

In case you are interested in using Chain.jl in addition to DataFrames.jl, Bogumił Kamiński's answer might then look like this:

```
julia> using DataFrames, Statistics, Chain

julia> df = DataFrame(a1 = [1,1,3,4,6,6], a2 = [1,2,3,4,5,6]);

julia> @chain df begin
           groupby(:a1)
           combine(:a2 => mean)
       end

4×2 DataFrame
 Row │ a1     a2_mean 
     │ Int64  Float64 
─────┼────────────────
   1 │     1      1.5
   2 │     3      3.0
   3 │     4      4.0
   4 │     6      5.5
```

Comment: I don't think the _ is necessary if it's the first argument. One can simply `groupby(:a1)` with @chain, same for combine